# How to choose two lights lighting for pure black background and dark clothes with post-production?

Tags: effects, vegas-pro, lighting, recommendation

I'm starting a low budget project that needs thousands of short videos [like this one](https://media.spreadthesign.com/video/mp4/13/49171.mp4).

I'm not an expert, neither a video production hobbyist, I don't know anything about Video Production. I did a little research and purchased a black muslin background, and two dimmable ring led lights.

The ideal result I'd like to achieve is like the following image:
[image: Girl with nice lightning at the front and pure black background]

The thing is that I want the [actor's clothes](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAwMDQsNCxAODBANEA4QExYRDRASGR8dFhsVHhgYEx4YFRsVFBwYGyAZHhsjKyQpIyA6LCYxGSYoRC5FOUsyLkIBCA4NDhITDhERExMREhYTJxsSES4cHR8TKQsfERYeFhcfEBYZHBAXIRcpDCMRCy8gKBwUJxYSERQeFg4bHTAeIP/AABEIAXUBVgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xACOAAEAAwEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAcFBggQAAIBAwIEAwIICwcFAQEAAAABAgMRIQQxBUFRYQZxgRKREyIyM6GxstEUFiNCcnN0krPB8BU1RFKC0vE0VGKD4SbCAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQEBAAICAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAREiIVECYWL/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APVQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPhcf8RUOFJ6bTJVta43jH82HeYH0OOcb03CKGbT1VRP8ABqH859Io8X/GTxDS4hOqtfqbTleUG7wXlCV4ovqa1fU1Z6jU1JVa88znJ/QuiXJH52v89Kz3I09G03jPjtLFaOl1Mes4uMvfBqJ9aHjyG1bQT86dX74Hm1N+3Tg+yQftID1SPjzhfPS65ekP95b8eeDrahrfdH/eeT7bEPp7mUepz8e6BfNaPVy83BHBV8fVb/kdBBfp1fuged3z0Ia5crgfrp+OOP1a96UNJTpQy6ahv2k5ybPVuG6/S8T0dPVaWScJrK5xlzjLujwClZKT2urM+jwji+s4Lq/htN8ejNr8IofmSj/KRB7eDLhfF+HcV03w+jqqVrfC038uD6TRqVkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+RxXxRwrh16cG9VqVj4Kjsv057RA+uc+v41wjhkbaqvBT5UoZqPyjE8t4j4o41rrpVPwak9qWnx+9U3Z+WbbbbeXvbd+bYV+54v4011dSpcNh+CUnhVZ5rvyWYwPycZSqRVSbnOpK7nKT+Nd83fOTiUUs29WdNKzi+zCtM2afPmfC1KUa/ofeaVrnx9fFtxnbZ+ywNNJJum1h2Z0Wb3TPmadqNZJ7PB9Onp61aqqOnhUq1JfIpU03J7t2jG7djcvh1WeUNO10ncW3sdEuHcTjf29Jro2w/apz326FFouJO9tLrMK/zc/pwXT6NvTGzAnRnSnKFZVKdSPyoTupe7cz9mPn3f8A9GnVOXTFpU2+TZzSa5G8vi0oxtyuc2TnWm9HX67hlWGp4dWlQrbSa2kuk4u6aPTOF+OKLUIcYouk+eoo5h6wzNHkuoeIrzZ3xS9hLbCtfYg/oHS6rS6ykqukrUq1N/nQd/f0YPAKFbVaOv8AC6OtVoVF+fSk177PKP3fCvHGpo2pcYpKtDnqaOJ+sCo9EA0Wu0Ovo/DaKvSrU+bg8rtJbxfZoBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiTjGLlJpRSu29kgJM+J8W4fwql7esqWk/m6MM1J/oxPyfHPGFKhehwm06m09S8wXakvz2ebVq9fUVpV686k6k8yqTd5vzfIK/RcY8S8S4l7dKLel03OhTfxn+tmflrxt7PL/AC/1uM7LbmMp55oKi7krNbcyFu72Jtd2RKxsroCLdPW5rQeZJ3ezMVf2uvc1pNKbTzeNu/X6wN5Wbxe+7OHVRvSasd6Td7pdjCqsZf8AyB8BcnzR9ilUmkqtKUoTtiUHZrk7NZR82rD2J35M6dLP4jhzWY3IPo/hev8Ak/hOpSWfnJb/ALxouIcTun+Gau/L8pP/AHHJmxGW8FF6tSpWm6lac6lV/LnJty6K7d3gok7pO2cNEd3a303L0rZll+z9YFa81f2Tni01nYvUecmTdnZAZ1FerCJ9DfkcGHqlti31HcwHLJDQtLezIxbtzA102o1ejrxr6KtVoVY/nwdr9pLZrsz0HhPjrajxulbktVRX24Hm7t5sOzWbAf0NptTptXRVbS1adalLacHdA/n/AEeq1uhr/D6CvUoVebg8P9JfJkj0Lhfjvanxqjbl+FUPrnTCYfvgNNqdNq6Ma2lq061KWYzg7oBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG0k22klltnmHifjcuKah0NJUa0NHHarPnNrmlyPv8Ajjiro6eHDaE7Tr/H1VuVLlH/AFnmsMUpW2SxcKo1zu3Lm31K55l38anFprK+kon3yFRf6BhvtsGl3Id72AndP6yGyf6sHt3Aorc89jSlf4SLzva1vQzzbkPk+fIDteX9ZWSXPZbFu62ecdyrbV3uBwain7cX15nzqcnTmpdHlH3HFPbpm/uPm6mg0/hI5TxJEHXiVnumRs7I5tNVw6c8NZjc6XKPWy5lC3J89jaSVONu135kU17K+Fl/oXO/U56kpS/kgM57Xv5GcNy8voM7Wd9iCaGdS2tlf7jse/Pujk0qVpSfPB1eYBvKXvIWSXaxCvy9GiiMLC3Iw8ku6IwwIXki9lzZFu2S10su2FdLq+QH1eBcVr8F4nCrTdR6V/8AXUU942tdLa8T2zS6ilqKEK1CcZ0qiUqc47NH88095J7833P2vg7iktLq5cOrStQ1LvpXyjX6f+0iPVARF+0r+8kqAAAAAAAAAAAAAANVqKWk01XUVnanSi5y+5d2D8N444m7w4bReI2rar+UAPwPEdZW1+uraqs/j1ZuVuSXKK7RWDP4yo25HKrN/Ude1N26BWNJ3o2vthLuJ4z1/wCPrI02YyWzIbfsy7O69Qq0XjZeRDs2I5V+ZMrAR2j72Q8dX3JfqlYi/wDSAPObkNKzTJ59wgJVWssQcdrL2lf+aMXLXPaVFdMZ+s2I/qwHFJ65vNRLysv5G2moJ6mlLXVK34P7S+G9l3l7Pbdb9jVq6LL40WnywyDfWrT0tS6ejquvQlBVFKazBu6dNtJxbicMK/wcJS1G0Hakv88vLoa3ioyc7JRy/wCu58upOVabqT8oR5JAUcqlSTnUlL2nnDHx7/LqerJJV28ZIrZUtS/zpF1p6j+XPBvSc1C09zXDKisIKEVFZzllhZWIdig7PbAukMoJO2AIs7fzFrE2IcnuwEiebu8RV35kJXkiJO1O7/OftenIDOhK85vkby9tNOEmpRalGSw1JO6aOTTXvJnZFclzYHs3h/iq4joKeodlWX5LVx6VVz/17n3TxjwzxH+zuLxpVZW02stRq9p/mTPZ6Mrr2XvEIAAIAAAAAAAAAABr9ZR0Giq6qt8mlG9ubeyivNngus1FbU16letL2qlSbnU82fufG3FFV1MOH0neFC09R3qNYXojz1tSa77hULEl36HS8Rtuc0UnKy3Ol9FkK59O/jzVr5LS/Os18n6nYpRxXkaSsntupJ294FISxjFi778zOlmNvp7GnIB7rFb4w7i//wBRLeOlwI8gxdLr5E4vbFgI3V+hHZk2e/JkMCCY4d1vsE+/vJj8qzA49ZJfFgufxpeXI4z6FH8ElrZrV/IUXGnf5PtrC9q2bFp0aEatSVC7ot/kr729c2vexkcsKDkrzdl05nWoRStFWLO3awe9911KILb9ERu1byYKJzbtzRH1dCV2+kh29O4CzJte5BLYDnzsuZRlr/T1K9LP0Asvku13iyMdQ7Rx0Oj83bmvvODUSu/NkG+lVo36s2i7NvkVpr2aSRN755bMoiulJHsXhzib4hwujqJu9el+Q1n6a5/60ePPY/QeFOILQ8XVCo7UNclSn2q7wfv+0QezAjTzvFwe8SSsgAAAAAAAA4prqfDeH1tVO3xI/k4vnPaKB59434lGrqoaClK8aHx636x/7F9oK/DaitVrVp1ar9qdSTnVct227tnIld32T5FptuVyHhW96CrRxLyNp3WbZMod7+RpLbGV3COeHz90dEt0ut/pRyxt8Pe9jsavlLZgc0HZWuaJL2TPGxdNW6clcKPbpYZeMLug9yLW2vd7gTlem5GSbcskdmuyAWxbYNW8iWmiuzbYC+5MMzI5XRZO1n03A4KMVKpKTV7t2O1rHNGNL4qNW01h2IGSHYn0sg8lCVrXIxyTuTlZ97RHncCbYzYboj6g2gJd1z7MgZ5oPfyAPyKuysS/QO3s49wFpyfsx352x6HzmnKql3ydtRr2Y+TOOkr1cEH0rJRsrZ2MVubO1kuhguaXqyjXBhUT/NbTWU+5vHK+tmcr8/KwHs/AOJf2jw2hq5NfDJfBav8AWxsm/wDXufoTx7wfxBaPij0dWVqOutBdq6+R79j2DTzvH2XvEiJABUAAAAAHLxTWw4bw6rqp/mK1Jf5pvCR4hXqTrTnVqS9qrUk6lST3cm/abP2HjPif4Vr1o4N/A6XEu9Xn+6fhpbq4VVYZO+NyL46IlqyCpXe6RaXyFf1KRd0XqWtdP3AYU38bkjvjZpvmsnzoSakfQhZqVugHJ8XNrX7Fs4ZVq2y8mTF5tm+4Ft8bsrzRZ72IAgC/lgj12AnNu/0Bb5Jtjch4tzAeXPDLNWUbfKd7InLlj3Mo5fHunmzSAonnBolJq1jO77ll9HOxAvjYX2x5IJu+GyWktyiv9JBWav0LO7eXaJG/TqAwldEZ5kxunzTIbAjfrYn6ibNkefmmBHuD25k5GLdGBjWfxV+ic2n+NUZtqJWgn1TRnpFeb8iD6D+TgwRvLKwcyy2Uaq1iJBJFnbLyBhL2laUW4yg04SW6azc9v4HxJcQ4fp9ZhTkvY1CXKrHEvfv6niUt3c/XeC9f8Br58PqfN6vNHtXX++JB64CKE7ws94klZAAAM+M69cN4bW1OPbS9mgnzqPY0POfGfE1qdctFSd4aX5feq9/3APxdWbnKUnJuTk5Sbe983ZzOzkncvK3lcpi9kGhX3x1LTVo4IjbmKtkBWln0L1MxvyKUmaVMwuvIDkg83PoQdqc3nbB8252U3elK3YCl82xgK9uxCV9i/wDPYB7vLqRlIn1bYd7v6QKuxPMi3S9rkrv6MCfUK/8AW5BN/cuYBP15+ZXm7rBOLYzyJW3YCmxKbwyrtcsuy23ZBOCbyvZ27k/FtzKvLzkBm3Mi973wS8c7dLkcvrAZSTWxDsSAF2yU28WuS+dgtr3KKNL3BLOMIl/TyI/pgcOpeEukmi+k+VLyRlqLqrZ8/jG2j+VLyVjI7Z4jfPY5s+1g6JXtzOdv45oaInkOlg9sWsBVrGPUzU6tGcKtJuNSnKNSnJbqSd0zXDZnJMg904Zroa3SafW0sRrwUprpPaUfRn1zy7wRrs1+GVH11Ol+qaPUNNU9qHsvdBlIAKK8W10eHcOrap2vCNqS6zeIo8IqznOTqTbc5uUpt8283Z+88c6mrLWUNJf8lCn8LZf525RyfgZq178tkFYt+plFSvdvctJ4T5chFtvqFbQS35oxq2udFna7wc07XAtSd72sWqu8XexWnjsmK2E0BzK9jpp2VGTd8ysjCGz2vsdUE1Qiucm5e9gUJvh79ESo9GRzt7gJW302KB5X3Eb9bLcCe+LMYG0c+g/q4FsWuRjsM7IhvAB9i7fJlL/8Ft+S+4gyzd9zSHTFmjO/l1LR2A0TeElgq+97+e5ZXKPlzAnbfmFZZIz2uS7tgRsL4z7mR25Mn6gHJY9SyT5Mgtbus7gRLbF10RVKV+5Lz5FFmXN8kBxatWqxfYtpPly8sk6y3tw353uRpd5EHc+xzu13uzolsc8tzQvHlcvbGfUpHa+OyNeWyAzXRFJddy7IdkBpodXPQcQ02rhf8jOMpJc4bSXrG57rQqwbhVpSUqVWKnCS2cWrpngMlaL5eZ6n4P1Pw/BFRcrz0tRws+UH8eJB+6BFGXtQQKy8z8T6Piq4lW1epoz+AnO1KrDMFDZXa2Pyk1CV9m+R7u7NWZ8XinhThWuvOgvwSv1pfI9YBXjM4JPrywVjFp4y17z73FOC8T4S76umpUb2hqIZpvzxg+TFLdPukFT+bdq5ySV59Dsna3Ncjmay8+aArHpyLVcRRS9i89nz6gYQdo2ti9jslb2VFXdoq/uRyLEfqOyrva3KwGT2SxZFZYRo3eN7GFwJxj2d+ZDf08gs4IypWILxS2bQS5ZZF1vZll5+QDkiLXd8Ind3I279gLc+fkxtHL9LFVv35lmBk2Xji1yjeGWj5eoGid78inPazJXo+WSvPl1YE2uw8dkL38ybO1sAVBF+RPfPkBKLKyWyI6L3FksgQ+680ZbyX0Gr73fRmbA5tZ+a+hOmSjG75karMF1ua0bKlDyA2lldDBp8jodrdTC3yn6FFlYu7WXQzgm9smytytJp+l+4FUms8upm78sLf2n/ACRduKzPL+j0R97hnAOIcTcalRPTabnVmsyX/hEg/OQhOpUjSownUqzdoxiryb7WPTPC/Bdbwx1dVrJ+xOvBQelXndSn3Pt8O4Xw7hcLaSkvbfy60szZ9HLYTLq00/ZbBtQpezH2pAqLgABKMZRcZJSi1aSeU10Z+R4x4Oo1XKvwhqhV3eml80/0OcD9cAPDdVQ1GkquhraU6NWP5kvri8prujicLnv+v4foeI0PgdbShVhvFv5UX1g1mLPLeN+GdbwtOtpvb1WiWXJfOQ/TQafj7XuQ2/ZNm04nJP2nKMKUZTqTdoQirtvyWQIau8uyO6os7L3n63gvhBKC1XHJXdrw0Uff+WZ+RqNOU08K7AxdufoZSy+SNHe/YyzkC3ILmveTsiMuXQgm1uhdWItyRZJ87AVtyd+xVrOC17Oy5lfq5gWXS5Mu+LlF9WzLywnvbqwMG3leqLx6v6SjLxyBp/VjN3vyNFdK5nL6e38wJWeq6lneybKxu7NF3fZcwMwg+nchejfMDVJvvYlWfbyIWbYRKWbZ8wJsrGD58+5tgxlvtjoBnUp1a7jRoRlUqzdoQisyfYvBWUYyTU0kpRas011Tyj6HBrrj/DmsNV4HoviHgNLikJ19IoUuJRzGWyq9pgeYcsZ5swt1xfkt3zNatPU6ebp6ijVpVU3GUakWrNedrhK3WUpYxu3ySSyBVbWeI84L/wDpnbpNHqtdUVLRUpVH2xGPm9kfp+FeFp1kq/E3KnTeY6dYm/03yP3dCjp9NSVLTU4Uqa2jBWCPzXCfDOk0dq2utqdTuk/m4eSP1Ny0YSm8HfS0qWZlRxQpymd1OjGGd2CQAAAAAAAAAAA/H8f8Gw1k3qeESpaeu81aE8UZeVk3Bl+C+HqHBl7c7V9fPE6/KPakfrSArOFC1GdSp/ldl6Hg0pL2pO3M991Ltpqz6U5/ZZ4E/ZafS90BjLCexnlmksJmffHRkVdbWbHdvyZW+OxK5K6A0Vud7sm8UnvboRa9srAknbf1KKvfLfZEcxKxEWQWV9hJIlYs9u4k3YDFsvD6OZm+qNIgaq1sPyMm85t3NV295nJ9vMBHY0v3yZwtk0St2AzaKx2ZeSfPmZXd7oDVF1zuZxz/ADNFbnkA9uzMG0nv5m7t08kYSvYDu4Jnj2g/XwPan8s8Y4Cr+IdB+u/k2e0LNVeYSujiPDNBxLQ/Aa2mpp5hPacZdYPkfm+FeF9Pwm9epP8ACtTdqnNrEY9kfqwVHz1Ccnsbw07eZHSAEYqKsgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGuutDqbb/A1LfuM8Be2bJ9D37XK+h1K60an2GeBNq1m/QKwdljoZ/WaPCM0RVi0Er9Sis8YLpcwLlZdi+LfS8lHiIFG82t5MR75IdvuLRv3AusIifoySr2sBmzSKZjyybIC7WDOf9M0dvTkUe7tt0AiFudrm2fZd75MI3Nd74sBV3t9BkayMXZ+YGkWr25G11fa9jGLaNml0ae+QIatuYyX/ANRs/p5mMgPp+HM+ItCv/OX2Jns0PnV5njXhu34x6H9Of8OZ7LD51eYSu4AFQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANZ/wBFqP1NT7LPAJYW2T3/AFWdJXXWlP7LP5/lncKyltvsZfW+RpO73KIitFZLNyU9rFDRYYEvbkykjSWEYy2Apvfkax2yZX5YNY2sBZ9EUfPc0/kZyx8kDNefmaxsjNJ9mXjnyA0u2Z7vsi2XlehSXcAtzVGUejRsgKyysbmEuxs7oyd2BaG+bZWWzeO6OeBummBDSuZS9DWTve/XCZlJJgfV8Nr/APSaH9Kf8KZ7LT+dR454ZT/GPRedT+FM9jpfPLzCV2gAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABqsaSv+qn9ln8+s/oHW40Op/U1PsM8AldhWUjOKzsTLfkQiKvt5GkUZI2jf1Al3urHPLm0zebtE5546NgUTXTJsrp9zGDebmy5PDA17trsYvui7be/MpLPd7egFe6NEr+e5mumC6eN8cwL+d7lHYs/c+Vyr9nG1wC7GiuYrfzNkt3suSASvl7uxgzZ7GL+S7AIe7lZm6ZhA3jflsBM8GEsdOxtK2bbGXID7HhjPiTR/wDt/gzPYqXzy8zx/wAL3/GTSeVX+FM9fpfPLzCV3AAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABrv+h1P6mp9hn8/O6u2rH9A8Q/u/VfqKv2Gfz8//K90RWMnfqyOeCZ/8FFa+9mFar17GsU0rGUbXNobXeLrAFan0nK9zpqPqrL6fU5ZXAQwjdNtGEcM2SugJ2uVl35mjWLuxjLG2/MAkXRRW5F43AuzN5fJsu2ZtWb5MAnY1VrGKvg1uAfOzMZWNpZMX0XogEDdb9O5grG0UgJk1jBne6NHtflzM/L3gfb8LZ8SaXyq/wAKZ69S+eXmeR+FL/jHQ7Qq/YZ67R+dCV2gAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABxH+7tX+z1fsSP59k7xP6C4l/dmr/AGet9iR/Psts2CsG2wseodnvgnN+RFX59fI0SdjON+3c1WFj3lGdS/I55dUbz2vz5HO3jBAT5+83XI5+Xc3je4GnuyZS+kvK1jN9wI5bGkbp/cUs74LJLcC7zuzOTzc0d10XcykAjizsarrgyia+meYESvaxlK26/pGzuYy9wELc33t2MYo2WG+QEvvsZGzxyMdm0B+g8JL/APQ0f1dX7B63Q+dPJPCKt4hpfqqv2T13T/OhHWACoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI4njhes/Zq32JH8+ya9lN37H9B8UzwvW/s1b+HI/nqVrX5cgrJ7krfbzIJjl4Ct1e/nt1LJJb8yvL+ZKyuvJgZzOdm82ks7nPkgJ4wbxvbmcqOmGUBpK1jFp8vQ0llZM3e4E2sWTIv3wxz6IDTdXMZG17LmjGW11zARecYN11W5hF35GyAlmE7WN36GM7ZeAIjubcuRzrc3W17ASrozluacjMD9D4Q/v8Ah+pqnrmndqp5H4Rx4gh3o1D1uh86ErsABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEcT/uvWfs1b7Ej+e3625M/oXi+OEa79lr/wAOR/PT9b9OQVm+hKWdyrLxvu7EVr2e3Im63+oK6y9mStijCo8XMX0ZtO1jB4uQZp2yjrja31nFFZSO2DxtZATLHXYy59zSb6JFN9gL+WxC3uW5dCiywNXmNjCRs8LJhMCYm6MI7G0MeoF3ZGMrbdTV+ZjJNsDJYZ0R25+hztZN4gW2W6vuZt+q5l2u5RgfofCN/wAYafelVPW6Hzp5P4Pjfj6fShUZ6xQ+dCV2gAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACOL/ANz6/wDZK/8ACkfzy1uf0Nxj+59f+yV/4Uj+eX/wFUx6svEpzwaxtts+ZFaPl9TDWSL3Xxrr7/QcuXb/AOFGMzCTw73N54v9JzvJBWFzpi3ZKxzxujdd2gLSWd7kLMsB3CQGkr+za2DJb2NZbZM4rzA1e1znk82N5P4t1uc1m2BeJqrmceisapZAu27ZMX0uzV9nkyfTHmBlL0aLwZD2zl8kREDbBXdCRGAP0/gzPG6nbTz+uJ6vpVeqeV+Cs8Zr9tNL7cD1XSfOMI6gAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABjx3HA9f+y1fsM/nw9+8Ry9ngGv8A1El78HgcVfYiqpI0jZLOzItYuou3Iqpt09yJ5YRZLPIh2eFZAc0+uxhI6amOZyztfDIEbGy5bdzONuTVi6Vt3YC9uaLxUlyXcrFX3NbK24FJehVXXZlrJZx2uGkwIlfl6mG8jVruZq1+oF4rdGiyZqzt9xtFZtnvdATJuyRi7rJu1Le5m1kDHDdglZlnEWuBL2I+smzsQkB+u8E/3rqu2m+ucT1PSWu2zy7wTjieqXN6f6po9T0bUbsJW4AKgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA5PEavwDX9qEn7sng8Zr2cH9BSjGUXGSUoyVpJ5TTxZnHq+D8JqWto9GnztTj/JBXhLkt7ryLxkkeyPgfDOei0n7kSj4Fwv/sdL+4gPH3JKzwQ5p32PYHwPhi/wWm/cRX+yeGR/wmn/AHI/cB4zUkkcs5qx7h/ZvDP+10/7kfuLrQ8OW2m0/wC5H7iGXh0JR5mvtXkllo9xWn0kfk6egv8AQvuO7S6anUd3CnGC3tFAy8Hi0kskuUb/ACj+gnpdK18alSfmkUfC9BP5yhp2u8I/cB/PrktyL4teyPd5cC4TPfR6P1pR+45ZeG+By30Oj/cA8QnKKVmzK6ue4fi3wNO/4DpPWJvS4DweDv8AgGgX/qh9wHhsalO7XtKxvBxct0f0DHhvDIK0NHo15Uo/7Q9Bw9/4bTLyhH7gPAHOKTMG47M98qcJ0U96Gn9YL7j51TgfDHl6LSv/AERA8SbQXs3/AJHscuB8H56HTfuIp/YnBP8AstP+6B4/eN3lEXgujPY1wbgq/wADpf3EW/sfgz/wGl/cQMvxfglJ8S1co7RoJPzc0ep6N2bZ8jS8P0ejcvwLTUqDqW+EcFa9trn29LCUItywUWAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAA6VN8is9LCKywAMPgI9TqjFRVkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHTg+SAAfB0+iFl0QAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//2Q==) to be distinguishable from the background, while wearing a nice dark grey t shirt like in the photo. I was thinking about using one light as back light for a soft "white aura" at the borders of the actor's clothes and hair.

[image: actor clothes are dark grey polos]

The muslin alone doesn't make a pure black backdrop, so at post production I'm going to lower the shadows and brighten the middles and lights (?).

But can I use a back-light and a fill light to achieve this?